# Install (build) C++ dependency for Windows using g++ with cygwin

Tags: g++, cmake, cygwin

For context I'm completely new to cmake and C++ compiling. I'm trying to compile an application only available for linux in windows using g++. That application has a 3rd party library which I need to install/build on Windows as well.

That library uses cmake. When running cmake it defaults to "Building for: Visual Studio 12" and then fails due to an issue with time.h Anyway how can I set it to use cygwins g++ instead of visual studio? Or am I misunderstanding soemthing? I also tried this to no avail:

```
cmake ../ -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=g++

cmake ../ -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:STRING=g++
```

Where can this setting be configured so that it will take the compiler I desire?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need ["Unix Makefiles" generator](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#section_Generators) :

```
cmake .. -G "Unix Makefiles"
```

Comment: And ensure that the cmake used is the one from cygwin and not the naive one from windows